# Cannot Launch League of Legends Game with Unknown DirectX Error

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues, directx-9

When I try to start the game, it shows me the following error. what can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known error with the new patch (7.9).

One fix that seems to be working for a majority of people is the **[config reset](https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support-en/quucoRoO-an-unknown-directx-error-has-occured?comment=0000)**

Try this:

1. Go to `C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config`
2. Delete `game.cfg` file

   [image]
3. Launch the game, does same issue occur?

Since this is a rather common issue Riot has also started a **[support thread](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/nxyEq9WA-532017-14-screen-directx-error-issues)** in the official forums.